# Twilio: delete all messages given a phone number

Tags: twilio

Is it possible to delete all messages with a single API call given a phone number?

I understand there's an API to delete a single message by message ID. And I can get the list of messages to get message IDs. But I don't want to make multiple API calls to delete. I was wondering if twilio provides a way or if there's a workaround to delete all messages in a single API call while **keeping the same phone number**.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid we do not have any bulk action API endpoints at the moment, so you will need loop through all your messages and delete them one by one.